# Dynamic UITableViewCell height with lazy loading of images in cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, lazy-loading

I have a UITableview which showing Facebook news feed. There are some images in each news feed with different size. So i have to load these images lazily and at same time , i have to set the cell height according to the image height(which are not loaded when callling heightForrowAtIndexPath).

The problem is i don't have the image width and height if its not downloaded.So how to set cell height according to the images in that cell ? I googled a a lot .Lazy loading examples showing only images with fixed size.Please help me..Thanks in adavence.

Comment: did you ever find the answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

Well you can't know the size of the image before you download it.
You can check in the `heightForCellAtIndexPath` if the image is downloaded. 
Then set the correct height, just call `beginUpdate` and `endUpdate` on your table view after you downloaded an image.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load images in background thread initially don't show any images then from background load these images as fast as your image is load, reload the table form the background then set a bool variable for identifying that image is loaded.

And adjust the height accordingly, also you need to fix a size of imageView where you are going to show the images. No need to make it big or small. make it fixed(suppose 40*40).
Then you can adjust your cell.

For reloading the table from background use this line of code in you background selector

```
[self.yourTableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Find below very good apple official example.

[LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/LazyTableImages/index.html)

From Apple doc.

> This sample demonstrates a multi-stage
>   approach to loading and displaying a
>   UITableView. It begins by loading the
>   relevant text from an RSS feed so the
>   table can load as quickly as possible,
>   and then downloads the images for each
>   row asynchronously so the UI is more
>   responsive.

Comment: But in "LazyTableImages" all images are in same height.So cells also having same height.In my case images are of different sizes..

Comment: whenever an image is downloaded and ready to draw, you could call the `reloadData` on you `tableView` and you need to calculate the height of cell in `heightForCellAtIndexPath` function. **BUT** it will downgrade the table performance.

Comment: downvoted since the answer is based on an example which does not address the users question on dynamic height.